# Creating a New Table (Model) and Relating it to auth_user in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to create a new Model to keep track of the current password and the most recent previous password used. I want it to look like this crude example:

```
ID --- CUR_PASS --- PREV_PASS
1  --- 123      --- 321
2  --- 456      --- 654
```

Is it possible to make the *ID* the **username** in my **auth_user** table?

Here is the class I have so far:

```
# class model to store previously used passwords
class oldPass(models.Model):
    # username = models.ForeignKey('something') --> instead of ID?
    current_pass = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prev_pass = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:  # meta class to define the table name
        db_table = "old_pass"
```

I am trying to make it so I can have the ID be the username and when changing the password in **auth_user**, check back to the **old_pass** table and compare the values making sure it is neither. If it is either of em, kick back an error.

My biggest issues are these:

1. I don't know how to import auth_user so I can assign the username to this new table
2. I don't know how to change the ID to be the username instead of numbers. (Would this be done using ForeignKey?)
3. I want to be able to compare the values to a passed in variable...

Example of #3:
 - I want to execute User.set_password('pass') (so that the pass is hashed), I then want to compare this new password to 'current_pass' and 'prev_pass' before committing User.save(). If the password matches one of the passwords used, I want to abort.

*I am using Django 1.9 and Python 2.7.13*

**UPDATE**
So looking at the answers received and more info researched... This is my new class

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# class model to store previously used passwords
class oldPass(models.Model):
    # username = models.ForeignKey(User) --> instead of ID?
    current_pass = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prev_pass = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:  # meta class to define the table name
        db_table = "old_pass"
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why not just `models.ForeignKey('auth.User')`? Why do you need that to be the "ID" (whatever you mean by that)?

Comment: That's fair, I feel I didn't clearly explain that. I wanted to have the ID field be the username instead of the normal 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. layout. I realize from L.Xiao's answer down below, the ID field isn't that important I suppose. I really want to have 3 fields, username, current_pass, prev_pass.. and to set the username, I want to pull it from the auth_user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `from django.conf import settings`, and `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is your auth_user model.
2. Use a custom id like this `id = models.CharField(primary_key=True)`. But mostly, ID should be a meaningless field.
3. You can check the password before execute `User.set_password('pass')`.

models.py

```
class oldPass(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`)
    current_pass = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prev_pass = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "old_pass"
```

views.py

```
if oldPass.objects.filter(user=user, pre_pass='pass').exists():
    raise Error
user.set_password('pass')
user.save() #at the same time, update user's password in oldPass
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, #1 definitely helps. Would I assign a username variable by doing something like `username = models.AUTH_USER_MODEL.username` ? As for #3, I'm not sure what you mean by that.. Are you just confirming my example for #3? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the update, I have added my new class to my question. One last question, how do I import my new class? `From django.models import OldPass`?

Comment: `from app_name.models import OldPass`